# What is the status of Linguistics.SE?

Tags: discussion

Some proposals in Area51 were closed after beta version. What is the current status of linguistics.SE? Will it continue to live?

Comment: Relevant blog post — **[Does this site have a chance of succeeding?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/)**

Answer (score 2):

Those proposals have been closed because they probably didn't show enough activity, that is the usual reason.

We are not the best at the moment, but we are showing activity. Our visits are also increasing.

What you can do to help us (and yourself, too) is share our site, spread it. Don't spam, but for example, sharing a question now and then in Twitter or Facebook will help. :)